# wifi not working after kernel update to 5.13.0-27-generic in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, kernel, network-manager, iwlwifi

My laptop is HP PROBOOK with Ubuntu 20.04 installed. Last day my system kernel got updated to 5.13.0-27-generic and after that, I am not able to connect to wifi. The LAN connection is working fine but the wifi connectivity issue is there.
Following is the kernel detail -

```
Linux version 5.13.0-27-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-045) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 14 00:32:30 UTC 2022
```

It used to work fine before taking the update, but suddenly after the restart, this issue has arrived.

I am not sure whether my drivers are missing or something went wrong with the wifi adapter.

In case of missing drivers where to get these drivers from and same with wifi adapter.

`dkms status` throws the following result

```
rtl8821ce, v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.13.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce, v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.4.0-96-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu, 5.8.7.1, 5.13.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.11.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.13.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.4.0-96-generic, x86_64: installed
```

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network:0               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-22-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-59.u ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:600324c000-600324ffff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 20
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.11.0-22-generic firmware=0.6-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:143 memory:54100000-5411ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: veth4fc7862
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
```

`lspci -nn`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a14] (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a49] (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a03] (rev 01)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a0d] (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a13] (rev 01)
00:0e.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller [8086:9a0b]
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0ed] (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0ef] (rev 20)
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0e8] (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0e0] (rev 20)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0b0] (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a082] (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0c8] (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0a3] (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0a4] (rev 20)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V [8086:15fc] (rev 20)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:a809]
```

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

`ls -al /lib/firmware/*.pnvm`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 41804 Jan 10 15:49 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27456 Jan 10 15:49 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
```

`modinfo iwlwifi | grep -i a0f0`

```
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000A0F0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

`ls -al /lib/firmware/*pnvm*`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 41804 Jan 10 15:49 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm.HOLD
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27456 Jan 10 15:49 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm.HOLD
```

Comment: At the GRUB menu, try booting to a previous kernel and see if wifi is working. Also, edit your question and show me `dkms status`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Hey @heynnema , thanks for looking into the question. I have added the command result, Please have a look.

Comment: It looks like you have two rtl88xxxx kernel modules installed on kernel 5.13.0-27. Which one is correct? Boot to kernel 5.4.0-96 and see if wifi works again. Report back.

Comment: When booted to the -96 kernel, show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `lspci -nn`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: @heynnema - I booted the machine with  -96 kernel but the touchpad stopped working, so I booted again with 5.11.0-22-generic and thanks the wifi starts working again. I have added the results of the command you suggested.

Comment: Hey @Someone - thanks for looking into the question. I have rebooted the system with 5.11.0-22-generic , the wifi has started working and have added the result of the command you asked for.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /lib/firmware/*.pnvm`.

Comment: Boot to the -27 kernel (wifi should be broken again) and show me `modinfo iwlwifi | grep -i a0f0`.

Comment: @heynnema - added the detail (yes the wifi again stop working)

Comment: Please see my initial answer. Report back. Also... do you know why `dkms status` shows the rtlxxxx kernel drivers? Do you have additional network adapters?

Comment: @heynnema - I might have installed those drivers while troubleshooting the problem (though am not sure). I have tried the initial answer, wifi still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133615/discussion-between-heynnema-and-babita-bisht).

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls -al /lib/firmware/*.pnvm`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 41804 Jan 10 15:49 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27456 Jan 10 15:49 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
```

Rename these two .pnvm files to .pnvm.HOLD, reboot to 5.13.0-27-generic kernel, retest wifi.

**Update #1:**

Just to clean up dkms...

`dkms status`

```
rtl8821ce, v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.13.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce, v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.4.0-96-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu, 5.8.7.1, 5.13.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.11.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.13.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.4.0-96-generic, x86_64: installed
```

`sudo dkms remove rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 --all`

`sudo dkms remove rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1 --all`

`sudo dkms remove virtualbox/6.1.26 -k 5.4.0-96-generic`

**Update #2:**

Well, it looks like the 5.13.0-27-generic kernel breaks wifi for this user. Run with 5.11.0-46-generic kernel for now. Watch `Software Updater` for kernel updates newer than -27, update, then retest wifi.

**Update #3:**

HP ProBook 640 G8 Notebook PC

You have BIOS T74 Ver. 01.02.06. There's a newer BIOS available, version 01.08.01 Rev.A, dated Jan 27, 2022, and can be downloaded [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-probook-640-g8-notebook-pc/37934156). Note: The web site may tell you that it can't find your Ubuntu OS, so you have to manually tell it you've got Windows 10 64-bit 21H2.

Install the BIOS update. Reboot to -27 kernel. Retest wifi. Report back.

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS

**Update #4:**

Kernel 5.13.0-28 was released today 1/31/2022.

Comment: Not able to download the file. Also the file will be an .exe file so not be able to install it directly(not used wine).

Comment: @BabitaBisht Wine won't work. You don't have Windows installed? Some BIOS will allow updates directly from the current BIOS itself. Otherwise, go to http://www.freedos.org/ and try and build a bootable FreeDOS USB that has the .exe BIOS updater file on it.

Comment: The system doesn't have windows.

Comment: @BabitaBisht Did you check the current BIOS to see if it can be updated from there? Did you try FreeDOS?

Comment: @BabitaBisht I just checked. You can download the .exe file with the newer BIOS. When it comes up and tells you that you need some HP software that you don't have, just click on the link at the very bottom of that download dialog, and the download will start.

Comment: @BabitaBisht A new -28 kernel was released today.

Comment: Hi @heynnema - apology, got busy somewhere- and accepting the answer just got out of my mind. Have accepted the answer now.  Yes, just saw the new kernel update and jumped to this question. Thank you for your support, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, so a couple of days of Googling, it is working now.

You need to update the GRUB.

Easy solution:
Go to Ubuntu Software Center and search for "grub customizer"
Click the General Settings tab
under "default entry" select "predefined" button and from the drop down chose the older version.
I chose "5.11.0-46-generic"
(this new kernel broke my wifi "5.13.0-27-generic")
click the save button
restart the system, it should work.

---

slightly difficult solution:

If you do not want to install grub customizer and want to modify the grub by your self, enter the command in terminal to open the grub file:

sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

Now in the gedit remove or comment out this line:
GRUB_DEFAULT=0

and add these two lines

GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-46-generic"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="false"

save the grub file.

run the command to update the grub
sudo update-grub

restart the system, it should work.

Note:
5.11.0-46-generic was the version where my wifi was last working, for you it might be a different version, please check your system.

Comment: What you are calling the more difficult solution is the safest and preferred method. You can do a lot of harm using the wrong settings on that 3 rd party software.

Comment: Oh no. Not **GRUB Customizer**! It usually makes a real mess out of systems.

Comment: Oh Sorry, maybe I need to update my answer. Thanks @heynnema and  David. I used Grub Customizer without realizing the dangers of that tool but it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same case, but with kernel 5.17.9 on Ubuntu 22.04

Solution: Reboot. Press left shift during the grub boot, select older kernel such as 5.17.5